# Kotlin- a type annotation is required on a value parameter

Tags: kotlin

So I am not new to programming but new to Java and currently learning Kotlin through a course provided by Google. I reached the Dice Roller app and decided to do the **practice on your on challenges at the end of each session** where I have to roll 2 dices with 1 roll button but can not do that.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        rollButton.setOnClickListener{ rollDice(dice1) };  **//Error**
        rollButton.setOnClickListener{ rollDice(dice2) };  **//Error**

    }
    private fun rollDice(dice: ImageView) {

        val myDice = Dice(6);
        val diceRoll: Int = myDice.roll();
        val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dice)  **//ERROR**
        diceImage.contentDescription = diceRoll.toString()

        val drawableResource = when (diceRoll) {
            1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
            2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
            3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
            4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
            5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
            else -> R.drawable.dice_6
        }
        diceImage.setImageResource(drawableResource)
        }}

class Dice(private val numSides: Int) {
    fun roll(): Int{
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not post images

Comment: 1. What is your question? 2. Please copy your actual code to the question rather posting an image.

Comment: @marstran sure sorry, edited! My question is that why is there an error when I set a parameter and assign it but nothing is registered

Comment: the problem is that you're using `dice1` and `dice2` without having defined them. I.e., you need something like `val dice1 = ...` before you use it

Comment: (Strictly speaking, _dice_ is the plural of _die_: one die, two dice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have modified your `rollDice` function to take an ImageView parameter, so you can delete this line:

```
val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dice)
```

and you can change the line where you set the image to use the parameter that you passed to the function (you named it `dice`):

```
dice.setImageResource(drawableResource)
```

When you call this function, you have to pass the ImageView, so you need to create variables to find those ImageViews before passing them. Also, you can only set one click listener at a time. You need to call the `rollDice` function twice inside a single click listener. The way you're trying to do it, the first click listener gets erased when you set the second one.

```
val dice1: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dice1)
val dice2: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dice2)

rollButton.setOnClickListener{ 
    rollDice(dice1) 
    rollDice(dice2) 
}
```

Comment: Ahh man you are the best, did not really pay attention when writing code and now I realized I made some stupid mistakes such as writing 2 click listeners when I could just call it once calling rollDice twice inside its curly brackets